# WHERE string IN string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016-express

Right now I'm in a trouble and donot know how to solve it.

```
Declare @brand_id varchar(50) ='brand1, brand2'

SELECT related_brand_id FROM dbo.Category

=> result: Row 1: "brand1, brand3, brand5"
           Row 2: "brand3, brand5"
           Row 3: "brand5"
           Row 4: "brand2, brand5"
           ...
```

So, how can I select all rows in table Category with param @brand_id contain IN related_brand_id?

My expectation result:

```
Row 1: "brand1, brand3, brand5"
Row 4: "brand2"
...
```

Comment: You should avoid storing CSV like this in your SQL database.  Read about normalization of data in SQL.

Comment: please tag your dbms , and version of your dbms

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes I know, but It's an old outsource project from JP and I can't even modify it. My mission is try to fix it without change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016 and above, you can use `string_split`:

```
DECLARE @brand_id varchar(50) = 'brand1,brand2';

SELECT distinct C.*
FROM Category c
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(related_brand_id, ',')) s
JOIN
    (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@brand_id , ',')) v ON TRIM(s.value) = TRIM(v.value)
```

Output:

```
id | related_brand_id    
---+-------------------
 1 | brand1,brand3,brand5
 4 | brand2,brand5
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33eb2afb444b9ab5ccbd1f955340f8f5)*

Answer (score 0):

If replace your search string with these two similar strings:

```
Declare @brand_id1 varchar(50) = '%brand1%'
Declare @brand_id2 varchar(50) = '%brand2%'
```

Then you can select all rows that contain either of those strings with the following code:

```
SELECT related_brand_id FROM dbo.Category
WHERE related_brand_id like @brand_id1 or related_brand_id like @brand_id2
```

This would return your expected result.